# No internal docker IP address when I run mongdb image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm starting a container from an official mongodb image using command

sudo docker run -d --name mongodb mongo

Other containers I spin get IP address but not mongo 
When I run sudo docker inspect mongodb all the fields are blank

I'm running it on Ubuntu with virtual box and network interface is set to NAT

This is the output from inspect command.

{
"NetworkSettings":{
"Bridge":"",
"SandboxID":"16b808df46537e04ab2bf96e05dc41fd4660a270c927634c2a94a1639d32f693",
"HairpinMode":false,
"LinkLocalIPv6Address":"",
"LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen":0,
"Ports":{

```
  },
  "SandboxKey":"/var/run/docker/netns/16b808df4653",
  "SecondaryIPAddresses":null,
  "SecondaryIPv6Addresses":null,
  "EndpointID":"",
  "Gateway":"",
  "GlobalIPv6Address":"",
  "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,
  "IPAddress":"",
  "IPPrefixLen":0,
  "IPv6Gateway":"",
  "MacAddress":"",
  "Networks":{
     "bridge":{
        "IPAMConfig":null,
        "Links":null,
        "Aliases":null,
        "NetworkID":"f66bff6e962312af4d9af54ed9e5ba337d3d9466a5702ae8430660bfda690833",
        "EndpointID":"",
        "Gateway":"",
        "IPAddress":"",
        "IPPrefixLen":0,
        "IPv6Gateway":"",
        "GlobalIPv6Address":"",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,
        "MacAddress":"",
        "DriverOpts":null
     }
  }
```

}

Comment: What's your actual goal with dumping out the debugging information from `docker inspect`?  You never need the IP address that's there, and can't use it in many common setups; do you need a `docker run -p` option to access its ports from outside Docker, or a `docker run --net` option to connect from other containers?

Comment: I'm actually learning docker. Doing some Udemy course. For the guy in the course, it worked like, and I would like to follow the course flow because it is quite extensive. I guess later I will use -p option to let the web app communicate with the database. It is not a pro situation ;)

Comment: I also tried same on one of my centos machines which I use for a kube cluster.
Same result no IP assigned.

Comment: If you're trying this in a Kubernetes environment, Kubernetes has its own native networking layer that's very different from what you see in Docker.  You probably shouldn't use `docker` commands in a Kubernetes context at all.  Even on a native-Linux host, you can't access the Kubernetes-internal network without the client also being inside Kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips again, but I have prepared kube cluster but not using it yet. I'm doing a course which quite long first explains all the docker aspects then it will explain how this will work in kube.
I prepared 3 node cluster beforehand to don't use minikube

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem, however don't know is it a bug or my lack of knowledge
So far I was trying with mongo image (:latest)
I started trying older versions.
Went with mongo:focal - same result, no IP.
However, when I tried with mongo: 4.4.6-bionic
Everything went fine and I have IP assigned to the mongodb container :)

Comment: Does anyone know why it did not work before ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it directly on Ubuntu with Docker, but without virtualbox.
You could try run it like this:

`docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb dockerfile/mongodb`

Alternatively you can try run it with a docker-compose.yml file.
Put this in docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb-service:
    image: mongo


    ports:
        - 27017:27017


    restart: always
```

Then run:

`docker-compose up`

You might want to think of defining some volumes for persistent storage of your data too, but later on once you've solved this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but it did not work with both options. Just to clarify I'm running Ubuntu in Virtual box but host is windows.

Comment: Why don't you try install the Ubuntu overlay on Windows and then install docker on there and try it that way?

Comment: I solved my problem by using an older image mongo: 4.4.6-bionic, like in my answer above. I don't know, is it a bug or what?